# git alias arguments with default, without blocking the rest of the line

Tags: git, git-alias

Here's my alias for interactively rebasing, by default onto the point where my branch diverged from develop.

```
git config --global alias.ri '!git rebase -i ${1-$(git merge-base HEAD origin/develop)} #'
```

Without commenting out the rest of the line with `#`, writing `git ri develop` would get me `git rebase -i develop develop`. But with the `#`, I cannot add other arguments such as `-Xtheirs`. How can I allow arguments with default values while also having any number of other arguments?

One approach would be to add a dozen arguments with empty defaults: `${2-} ${3-}` and so on. But I'm hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Typically, you define the alias as a shell function that constructs the desired call, followed by a call to that function: `git config --global alias.ri '!f() {...}; f'`. Inside that function, you can do things like conditionally shift values out of `$@`, to construct explicit arguments for `git rebase`, before finally executing something like `git rebase -i "$branchhead" "$@"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of OP, simply replacing `${1-` with `${@-` works, since the rest of the arguments go right after the first. There are different ways to get all parameters: `$@` vs `$*` vs `"$@"` vs `"$*"`. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230318164746/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#special_parameters_and_shell_variables) for the differences.

However, none of these ways work in another case: when I try to alias `cf` as `config --global` with default value `-l`. For example, `git cf alias.rs 'restore -s'`: here `$@` turns the arguments into `alias.rs restore -s`, losing the quotes. The same issue occurs if I write the alias as a shell function.

It's better to let the alias look at the arguments without handling them directly, so you don't need to end with `#`:

```
git config --global alias.cf '!if [[ -z $1 ]]; then arg="-l"; else arg=""; fi; git config --global $arg'
```

Shorter version:

```
git config --global alias.cf '!git config --global $([[ -z $1 ]] && echo -l)'
```